# How do i run migration in Room Database to change primary key?

Tags: android, android-room

This is my table: the `id` column is *primary key*. I want to make `Doorway id` and `id` a *composite key*. Does `Room` supports that? If it does how can I do that?

New *Primary key* should be *composite* and should be like this:

```
primary key = id+doorway_id
```

My entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "hours")
public class Hour extends EntityModel implements Parcelable {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_ID)
    @PrimaryKey()
    @Expose()
    private int _id;

    // Need to discuss.
    @SerializedName("server_id")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_SERVER_ID)
    private int serverId;

    @SerializedName("entries")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_ENTRIES)
    @Expose()
    private float entries;

    @SerializedName("alerts")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_ALERTS)
    @Expose()
    private float alerts;

    @SerializedName("mag_level")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_MAG_LEVEL)
    @Expose()
    private float magLevel;

    @SerializedName("door_open")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_DOOR_OPEN)
    @Expose()
    private float doorOpen;

    @SerializedName("entryway_usage")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_ENTRYWAY_USAGE)
    @Expose()
    private float entrywayUsage;

    @SerializedName("year")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_YEAR)
    @Expose()
    private int year;

    @SerializedName("month")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_MONTH)
    @Expose()
    private int month;

    @SerializedName("day")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_DAY)
    @Expose()
    private int day;

    @SerializedName("hour")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_HOUR)
    @Expose()
    private int hour;

    @SerializedName("alert_rate")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_ALERT_RATE)
    private double alert_rate;

    @SerializedName("recorded_at")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_TIME_STAMP)
    private String recorded_at;

    @SerializedName("doorway_id")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_DOORWAY_ID)
    @Expose()
    private int doorway_id;
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I could not found a solution so I  found a workaround to this problem by simply dropping the old tables and creating new ones with the new primary key.
Complete way is 
1. Creating a new temp table with the changed primary key 
2. Copy the old data in the new temp table
3. Drop the old table,
4. Change the new table's names as old table

Answer (score 0):

No One answered, so using my comment as an answer that does the job.

> found a workaround to this problem by simply dropping the old tables
> and creating new ones with the new primary key.
> Here is how
>
> 1. Creating a new temp table with the changed primary key
> 2. Copy the old data into the new temp table
> 3. Drop the old table
> 4. Change the new table's names to the old table.